# TFS auto header?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible when using TFS server to automatically have it ensure a specific header exists in the top of each specific file type? Example, each c++ file should have a specific copyright comment at the top. (I know this is not really a programming question per say, but I wasn't sure of a better place to look for a solution).

Comment: This could be easily enforced with StyleCop for managed source code but probably not for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to have the coder put the statement in the first time and not let the check in proceed until its done. You can use a checkin policy to do this.

[See checkin polices and samples.](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000194.html)

There are quite a few [here](http://www.google.co.nz/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enNZ364NZ365&aq=0&oq=TFS+Checkin+po&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tfs+checkin+policy)